# Using Iterative For Loop to Find Factorials of Integers in C++

Tags: loops, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    unsigned int num; unsigned long long int fact = 1;
    cout << "Number = "; cin >> num;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        fact *= i;
    }
    cout << "Factorial = " << fact;
    return 0;
}
```

This is a sample code that I have written to calculate the factorial of any random positive integer. My conceptual concern is, why do we have to initialize the variable fact as 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when we multiply "0" by any value, it returns zero.

so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    unsigned int num; unsigned long long int fact = 0;
    cout << "Number = "; cin >> num;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        fact *= i; // 0 * i (i 1, 2, 3, 4...)

    }
    cout << "Factorial = " << fact;
    return 0;
}
```

```
...cmd>a.exe
Number = 4
Factorial = 0
```